# Is there any way of predicting local optimums in the search space?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm

I understand that most real world optimization problems will have local optimums in the search space, but is there anyway to know if sure?

If I could know for sure that there wasn't any local optimums to worry about I could safely apply a simple hill climbing algorithm to solve the problem instead of a more complex search algorithm such as a GA.

Sorry if this is a little basic

Comment: I think this is highly dependent on the problem. With simple problems I bet there are ways of finding local optima.

Comment: Based on the type of the problem, you can build a prediction based on something unique you know the global optima would certainly have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Most real-world optimisation problems are specific instances of NP-hard problems.  "NP-hard" means that every problem whose solution can be verified quickly in the worst case ("NP") can be encoded as a special case ("-hard").

I do not think anybody knows any hill-climbing heuristic for any NP-hard problem where each step can be worst-case-efficiently implemented and where an optimal solution is always eventually returned.  (I could be mistaken about this; this is a stronger statement than "we don't know any polynomial-time algorithm for any NP-hard problem" which I'm rather more sure of.)

As an aside, I would not recommend leaning too heavily on hill-climbing, genetic algorithms, simulated annealing, and such things if you are interested in finding globally optimal solutions to large instances of hard problems.  I wouldn't recommend using them at all if you're interested in finding globally optimal solutions to large instances of easy problems.  It almost always pays to study and exploit the problem's structure, or at least use a framework like mixed-integer programming or constraint programming that can make use of what it can find.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things you can check. If you can prove that your have a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function then "Any local minimum of a convex function is also a global minimum. A strictly convex function will have at most one global minimum".

Very often you can show that a local minimum at x implies a local minimum at f(x) where f() might, for instance, permute the co-ordinates of x/rename the variables in x. For instance, the solution to the travelling salesman problem is a list of points to visit in order, and any circular rotation to such a solution has the same score. This is a pretty big hint that, at least, the function you are trying to minimize is not strictly convex and may not be convex.

If you write a hill-climbing solver, you can of course run it from multiple random starts and see if it converges to the same place all the time.